# RedLaser configuration page closed

Tags: ios, xamarin, barcode-scanner

Last year we have bought a license of the RedLaser Barcode Scanner which is developed by Xamarin. Now we want to reconfigure our License but the Configuration Site is closed. Does some know something about it?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

The Red Laser SDK is no longer offered by eBay. However, Manatee Works offers RedLaser SDK Developers a free, equivalent Manatee Works Barcode Scanner SDK license for Android and iOS, with the purchase of a support package.

Answer (score 0):

RedLaser was developed (I believe) by eBay.  Xamarin just created bindings for it to be used in their platform.

Answer (score 0):

The Red Laser SDK for developers is no longer offered by eBay. Manatee Works offers their SDK to integrate barcode scanning in your apps.

Also there is another third party , Scandit which offers the same and at a cheaper price than Manatee